# stores object tags object is displaying in django admin site but i have registered stores and tags

Tags: python, django

I have written the following models but something is may be wrong because instead of name of tags tag object is returned in Django admin site:

```
from os import path
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

projectDirPath = path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)) 
storeImageDir = FileSystemStorage(location=projectDirPath + '/couponRestApiApp/static')

class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)               # Tag name
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                          # Store Name
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)                            # Store Popularity Number
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=storeImageDir)                              # Store Image 
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                                       # This is the text you see in the URL
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                  # Time at which store is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                                   # Time at which store is updated
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store

    def getStoreTags(self):
        p = self.storeTags.objects.all()
        return p.tag

class coupons(models.Model):
    """ This is the coupon model """
    couponValue = models.CharField(max_length=4)                              # Coupon value in RS.
    couponDescription = models.TextField()                                    # Coupon Description
    couponURL = models.URLField()                                             # Coupon click URL
    couponStore = models.ForeignKey(stores)                                   # Key of coupon to store
    tagName = models.ForeignKey(tags,on_delete=models.PROTECT)                # Tag names associated to coupon
    success = models.TextField()                                              # Count of the number of times people have made it work
    failures =  models.TextField()                                            # Count of the number of times this has failed
    lastTested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                          # When was the coupon last tested
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class app(models.Model):
    """ This is the application model which is using the API """
    appName = models.CharField(max_length=20)      # Application name
    appDomain = models.CharField(max_length=20)    # Application description
    appKey =  models.TextField()                   # Application Key 
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)             # Time at which Application is added is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)             # Time at which Application details are updated

class subscriptions(models.Model):    
    """ These are the emails that are subscribing """  
    app =  models.CharField(max_length=20)                                # The application where the email came from
    store = models.CharField(max_length=20)                               # The optional store on which the email wants an update
    tag =   models.CharField(max_length=20)                               # The optional tag on which the email wants an update
    emailID = models.EmailField()                                         # EmailID of the registered user
    active =  models.BooleanField(default=True)                           # They may have unsubscribed
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                    # Time at user subscribed to the alerts
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                    # Time at which user updated its subscription 

class tagsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tag', 'tagDescription', 'tagSlug')

class storesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('storeName','storeDescription','storeURL',
                    'storePopularityNumber','storeImage',
                    'storeSlug','createdAt','createdAt','getStoreTags'
                    )

class couponsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('couponValue','couponDescription','couponValue',
                    'couponURL', 'couponStore','tagName','success',
                    'failures','createdAt','updatedAt'
                    )

class appsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('appName','appDomain','appKey',
                    'createdAt','updatedAt'                    
                    )


class subcriptionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('app','store','tag','emailID',
                    'active','createdAt','updatedAt'
                    )

admin.site.register(tags,tagsAdmin)
admin.site.register(stores,storesAdmin)
admin.site.register(coupons,couponsAdmin)
admin.site.register(app,appsAdmin)
admin.site.register(subscriptions,subcriptionsAdmin)
```

But when i save data using Django admin site under coupons category instead of names of tag tag object is returned same is happening with stores ...
am i doing something wrong..here please help me out. I have registered all the entries but still it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define unicode to display properly:

```
class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)               # Tag name
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):  # <-- you have to "tell" Django which field to display in admin 
        return self.tag
```

Comment: You solution worked but when i clicked on coupons to add data coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found error is thrown